# ¿Cómo crear un boton y juntar un poco los elementos en android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

tengo un `NavigationDrawer` en mi código, pero los items aparecen muy separados unos de otros, hacia abajo como en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para juntarlos un poco? ¿y cómo hago para crear un botón dentro de ese menú desplegable?

La flecha roja indica lo que quisiera que es juntar los objectos para que estén menos separados el número 5 de la palabra "juegos".

```
<menu 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item

      android:title="juegos">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:title="5">
        </item>
    </menu>

  </item>

    <item
        android:title="Dinero">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:title="u$d: 55">

            </item>

        </menu>

    </item>

    <item
        android:title="Pais"
        android:id="@+id/perfilUsuario_fundaciones_ayudadas">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:title="7">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:title="Paises Ayudados">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:title="2">
            </item>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/pe"
            android:icon="@drawable/corazon"
            android:title="@string/historial"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/perfilUsuario_opciones"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/opciones" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/btn_cerrarSesion"
            android:title="@string/cerrar_sesi_n"
            >
        </item>
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Añade el código del layout, si uas Material Design debes respectar sus directivas de diseño y elementos, descubre cual es más apropiado para la representación de los datos. https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Comment: como añado mi codigo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que desea va contra los guidelines, de hecho en realidad no lo puedes cambiar si estas agregando dentro de un item un elemento menú y a su ves otro item:

```
<item    
      android:title="juegos">
    <menu>    
        <item
            android:title="5">
        </item>
    </menu>
...
...
...
```

Lo único que puedes cambiar aquí es el espacio entre los grupos, sobreescribiendo estos valores dentro de tu archivo dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">120dp</dimen>
```

Pero los espacios entre los elementos del menú no podrías cambiarlos, ya que la vista esta diseñada para mostrar únicamente el icono y el titulo:

```
  <item
                android:id="@+id/my_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
                android:title="Mi Titulo" />
```

Te sugiero otra opción como crear tus vistas personalizadas, por ejemplo revisa el NavDrawerItem (drawer_list_item.xml) de este **[ejemplo](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y también puedes hacerr uso de un ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

Para reducir el espacio entre los items simplemente reduce el valor del margin que estés usando en ellos. Por otro lado, te aconsejo usar padding si no lo estas haciendo. Si pudieses proporcionar el código de tu XML sería de ayuda a la hora de dar una respuesta más concreta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Mejor seria poner eso como un comentario y dejar las respuestas "para solventar"

Comment: ahi le respondi Francisco

Answer (score 0):

Un Navigation Drawer es un contenedor de otros View, por ende son personalizables, tendria que generar el layout del campo que contiene un ListView, asegurando en este un margin minimo arriba y abajo, posterior a esto usando un Base adapter dentro del activity que maneja la vista donde este mostrando el Navigation Drawer, cargar cada item del menu asociando el layout creado anteriormente, y ya finalmente el listview cargarlo dentro del Navigation Drawer.